# Adding custom metadata values to a PDF file

Tags: pdf, metadata

Is it possible to create custom metadata key/values for a PDF file?

I can see (from other questions here) how to add title, author, keywords etc. However, I'm creating transcriptions of historical documents and I'd like to add some additional metadata, such as the record office holding the document and the document accession number.

The idea is that (in the future) when I want to make them available on the web I can write an app that can read the PDF to extract the metadata (via something like PDFBox or iText) to include it in a HTTP POST.

Comment: an article by ross moore in tugboat: [Advanced features for publishing mathematics, in PDF and on the Web](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93moore.pdf) discusses metadata other than just the main bibliographic information for a document.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Package `hyperref`

Package `hyperref` supports the setting of arbitrary keys in the PDF information dictionary (see [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={
    RecordOffice={my office},
    AccessionNumber={42},
  }
}

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

However, these keys are not standardized, thus most tools will not show them. But you can extract them via a PDF library.

### Package `hyperxmp`

The PDF format also supports XMP (eXtensible Metadata Platform). More keywords are standardized there. See package `hyperxmp` of Scott Pakin.

Comment: That's great. I can add the metadata and query via Apache PDFBox.

Comment: For the people that wanna check if a property was added and the command has worked well, just try this on terminal ***exiftool -S -DucumentVersion myDocument.pdf***. This is for checking the property called "DucumentVersion". You should change it by the property that you just added. If the property appears, your property was added successfully

Answer (score 9):

There is also `pdfx` package. Here you have to add metadata as a separate `.xmp` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Keywords{pdfTeX\sep PDF/X-1a\sep PDF/A-b} 
\Title{Sample LaTeX input file} 
\Author{LaTeX project team} 
\Org{TeX Users Group}
\Doi{123456789} 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the aforementioned methods work inside latex environment. In case you want to change some of the metadata information after the pdf is generated then take a look at [my post-processing method](https://youtu.be/z_VhS4F7Df4).

This method uses only a text editor.

Comment: I do not think this is a valid answer, as a post-processing breaks the latex-workflow

Comment: As I mentioned, It is an alternative. Especially when the source `tex` file is not accessible.